# Export markers from Adobe Audition

Tags: audio, adobe-audition

How can I export markers from Adobe Audition to any other program (or to a file with a documented format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export markers in Adobe Audition CC as shown below. CS6 and older versions do not appear to have the ability to export or import markers.

Select the markers you want to export (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for all), right-click an empty area of the markers panel and click "Export Selected Markers". It will export it as a tab-delimited CSV file.

[image: Adobe Audition screenshot showing right-click menu and "Export Selected Markers to CSV" selected.]

You can also import markers as well using the "Import Markers from File" option.